# proper way of using OR inside sql statement

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

I'm using `dapper` micro orm in conjuction with `sql server`.

```
 string author = "some author name";
 var get_book_from_name = "SELECT BookId FROM Author WHERE FirstName OR LastName LIKE('%' +@AuthorName +'%')";
 var data = this.db.Query<Book>(getBookFromAuthorName, new { AuthorName = author }).SingleOrDefault();
```

and I'm getting error using OR statement in query statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT BookId FROM Author WHERE
    FirstName LIKE '%'+@AuthorName+'%' OR LastName LIKE '%'+@AuthorName+'%'
```